# Issue with changing Managed Accounts

Tags: 2013, windows-authentication, managed-account

I am attempting to change the passwords in the managed accounts, however the return is always "The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you "  I cannot figure out what I am missing, the CA has Windows authentication enabled for it, however it keeps preventing my changes.

Comment: what type of authentication you are being used? and how is changing the password?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug due to MS16-101. To "solve" this right now, you would have to uninstall the associated MS16-101 patches from SharePoint *as well as* all of your Domain Controllers in the Active Directory domain where the SharePoint Server(s) and Service Account(s) reside.

https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/09/ms16-101-prevents-sharepoint-from-changing-managed-account-passwords/